# How do I hide or turn these git/temp files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how to turn these off in Visual Studio ?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ4w3.png**strong text**

Comment: What makes you think these come from git?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about...not even sure how these temp files are being generated

Comment: I'd just delete them and check whether and when they're recreated. You possibly have the output or intermediate paths of some of your projects set incorrectly.